# Polar decomposition with respect to the nonstandard involution of quaternionic matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, quaternions

The quaternions admit infinitely many involutions. But up to isomorphism, there are only two: The standard one $t+xi+yj+zk\mapsto t-xi-yj-zk$ and the *nonstandard* one $\phi:t+xi+yj+zk\mapsto t-xi+yj+zk$.

It's fairly easy to show that quaternion matrices admit a polar decomposition with respect to the standard involution. It appears less easy to show that it's true -- if indeed it *is* true -- for the nonstandard involution - at least *only* for the case of nonsingular matrices. Does such a polar decomposition exist?

---

Let $M \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb H)$. The objective is to show that one can factorise $M$ as $M =(M\sqrt{M^\phi M}^{-1})\sqrt{M^\phi M}$, where the first factor should be unitary (with respect to the nonstandard involution $\phi$) and the second should be Hermitian (same). Be aware that multiple square roots may exist, so a "principal" one might need to be chosen.

Comment: I think you wrote your nonstandard involution incorrectly - I believe it should change two of the signs, not just one.

Comment: @Wojowu It needs to be an *anti*-automorphism of order $2$.

Comment: @Wojowu I'm saying that there are two $*$-algebras over $\mathbb R$ whose underlying algebra is $\mathbb H$, up to isomorphism. The nonstandard one is defined by $q \mapsto i q^\dagger i^{-1}$ where $q^\dagger$ refers to the standard one. This matches my other definition.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying. I forgot the standard conjugation is also an anti-automorphism over quaternions.

Answer (score 1):

The claim follows from the following two propositions:

**Proposition 1**: Every $\phi$-Hermitian matrix $H$ with all eigenvalues outside the nonpositive real numbers, admits a $\phi$-Hermitian square root $\sqrt{H}$ such that $\sqrt{H} H = H \sqrt{H}$.

*Proof*. Let $\chi(H)$ be the real representation of $H$. Let $P^{-1}\chi(H) P = J_{m_1}(\lambda_1)\oplus\dotsb\oplus J_{m_k}(\lambda_k)$ be the Jordan form of $\chi(H)$. We know that none of the $\lambda_i$ are nonpositive real numbers. We may therefore use Hermite interpolation to construct a polynomial $p \in \mathbb C[x]$ satisfying $p(J_{m_i}(\lambda_i))^2 = J_{m_i}(\lambda_i)$ and $p(J_{m_i}(\overline{\lambda_i}))^2 = J_{m_i}(\overline{\lambda_i})$ for every $i$. Importantly, observe that all of the coefficients of $p$ are in $\mathbb R$. So we let $\sqrt{H} := p(H)$. Since the coefficients of $p$ are real, we get:

- $p(H)^\phi = p(H^\phi) = p(H)$.
- $\chi(p(H)^2) = p(\chi(H))^2 = \chi(H)$, from which we cancel $\chi$ to obtain $p(H)^2 = H$.
- $p(H) H = H p(H)$

and so we are done.

**Proposition 2**: Proposition 1 holds for all $H$ which are $\phi$-Hermitian and non-singular, and with no other preconditions on eigenvalues.

*Proof*. It only remains to consider the case when $H$ has a negative real eigenvalue. We can perturb $H$ to $H + \varepsilon$, preserving its $\phi$-Hermitianess, but making all its eigenvalues be outside $\mathbb R^-$. Let $K$ be a square root of $H + \varepsilon$. By submultiplicativity of the operator norm, we have $\lVert K \rVert \geq \sqrt{\lVert H + \varepsilon \rVert}$. Similarly, by observing $K^{-2} = H^{-1}$, we obtain $\lVert K \rVert \leq \frac 1 {\sqrt{\lVert H + \varepsilon \rVert}}$. So we obtain that the square roots of small perturbations of $H$ have matrix norms within a finite band. By Bolzano-Weierstrass, we may produce a convergent sequence converging to a square root of $H$.